# Run code on Ember view parameter change

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatables, ember-data

A week ago I ran into a problem with emberjs and DataTables.

I was using ember-data to get data from the asp codebehind using webmethods based on the route parameters. Then I would use that data to create a table with datatables. However, when I changed the route, which changed the data and therefore changed the html, datatables would add the rows, but it wouldn't remove the old rows. In addition none of the functionality would work on the new rows and whenever I would sort, it would remove the new data.

Please let me know if anyone has a better answer than the one I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked and found a lot of questions on this topic, or similar topics; However all of the solutions were hacky or costly performance-wise. So I found my own.

It isn't perfect; I would love for ember to implement an event based on this.

I added a controller initially for navigating in my application view. The change event looks mostly like this:

```
paramsChanged: function () {
    if (this.type && this.filingType.value && this.year && this.period) {
        this.transitionToRoute('application');
        Ember.run.next(this, function () {
            this.transitionToRoute(this.type.value, this.year, this.period);
        });
        //console.log('persist');
    }
}.observes('type', 'year', 'period')
```

This is changing the route to application(basically removing the sub view) then moving to whichever route I need next.

The performance cost, although untested, should be negligible. I need to run the code for creating the view anyway, and I'm already in the application. I'm destroying a little bit extra by transitioning to the index, then I'm recreating the sub-view on the next run loop causing the initialization code contained in didInsertElement to be run.